# i tried creating a javascript function that only runs once but its always running the else statement

Tags: javascript

i'm making a basic javascript function that works with onclick but it's always running the else statement which I only want it to run once

here's my script

```
function onlyOnce() {
    var runOnce = false;
    console.log("i'm running but i didn't go to the else statement yet")
    if (runOnce) {
        return
    } else {
        console.log("i'm running and i'm in the else statement")
        return runOnce = true;   
    }
}
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: You defined the runOnce variable inside the function and set its value to false. That is why the else statement is being activated. Define the runOnce variable outside the function and set it's value there or change the value given to it to true.

Comment: (That is, every time the function is run it accesses a *new* variable called `runOnce` that is initially set to false.)

Comment: (This would be good use/fun example of using a closure, possibly even writing a function to create it..)

Comment: @Maxi Panza ... just `console.log` the `runOnce` variable before the `if` clause and you can *"see"* yourself what both commenters before were hinting.

Comment: thanks to all who commented, i'm still learning javascript so your comments really helped me

Answer (score -1):

The `runOnce` variable is defined in the function, and after you leave the function its value is forgotten. When entering the function, its value will be set to `false` again.

One way to solve this, is by bringing the variable outside the function:

```js
let runOnce = false; // let is usually recommended over var

function onlyOnce() {
    console.log("i'm running but i didn't go to the else statement yet");
    if (runOnce) {  
        return;
    } else {
        console.log("i'm running and i'm in the else statement");
        runOnce = true;
    }
}
```

You could also make a class such that the function/method is associated with the data:

```js
class Something {
    constructor() {
        this.runOnce = false;
    }

    onlyOnce() {
        console.log("i'm running but i didn't go to the else statement yet");
        if (this.runOnce) {
            return;
        } else {
            console.log("i'm running and i'm in the else statement");
            this.runOnce = true;
        }
    }
}

let something = new Something();

something.onlyOnce(); // Prints second statement
something.onlyOnce(); // Prints first statement
```

Comment: Did you even try running your own 2nd example code? It breaks, due to not referring twice to `runOnce` via `this.runOnce`.

Comment: Still broken. I said **twice**. You are not a fan of code testing, aren't you.

Comment: Also `something.runOnce` is public accessible and not protected. Thus it can easily be overwritten/manipulated. If you were going to refactor the 2nd example into a true function-only, closure-based approach with some explanations to it, the OP would truly learn something important.

Comment: I haven't used that before, you are free to make edits.